# Por que os booleanos não tem uma classe em comum em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, booleano, design-de-linguagem

O Ruby não tem uma classe `Boolean`. Percebi que os objetos booleanos são de classes específicas dependendo do valor, veja:

```
true.class  => TrueClass
false.class => FalseClass
```

Diferente de outras linguagens, como C# e Java, em que `true` e `false` são do tipo `bool`, em Ruby é `TrueClass` ou `FalseClass`.

Isso implica em: se eu quero verificar se um objeto é booleano, tenho que fazer algo como:

```
def boolean?(value)
  [TrueClass, FalseClass].include? value.class
end
```

No caso, vejo como a única forma de ver se um objeto é de um tipo booleano. De outra forma, seria verificar somente se um objeto é truthy ou falsy.

```
!!nil #=> false
boolean?(nil) #=> false

!!"Olá!" #=> true
boolean?("Olá!") #=> false

!!false #=> false
boolean?(false) #=> true

!!true #=> true
boolean?(true) #=> true
```

Por que foi arquitetado assim? Que vantagens variar o tipo em questão do valor traz no contexto Ruby?

Comment: Tem algum contexto? Porque não precisa fazer isto.

Comment: Não preciso por conta do _duck typing_, né? @Maniero

Comment: Não precisa porque pode usar `true` e `false` como qualquer linguagem (https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/keywords_rdoc.html)

Comment: O problema não é nem a validação de tipo, foi um exemplo que tentei dar para contextualizar. Eu me deparei com `TrueClass` e `FalseClass` e questionei essa escolha. @Maniero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em um [e-mail questionando o mesmo para Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/96356), criador do Ruby, ele responde:

> > Algum bom motivo para que esses [`TrueClass` e `FalseClass`] não herdarem `Bool` ou algo do tipo?
>
> Existe alguma razão para herdarem `Bool`, onde `true` e `false` são só representações de valores verdadeiros?

Meu entendimento sobre isso é que uma classe é feita para agrupar objetos semelhantes em questão de valor, semântica e/ou comportamento.

No que disse Matz, ele não viu semelhança a partir desses critérios entre `true` e `false`. De fato eles são até opostos.

Para quem quiser ler mais sobre esse assunto, existe uma [*thread* no Ruby-Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4412411#1103364) que trata da mesma questão, onde Matsumoto também se prontifica.

> Não existe nada que `true` e `false` compartilham, portanto sem classe `Boolean`. Além disso, em Ruby, tudo se comporta como um valor booleano.